# JavaScript value not set during form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, post

I've searched for a solution to this issue all over the web. After no success, here I am. I have a form that where I have 3 fields that should contain data. Field 1 is the Zip Code, Field 2 and 3 are City and State respectively.

The JS function getCityByZipHome and getStateByZipHome dynamically return the city and state and insert the values into the the city2 and state2 input fields.

For whatever reason, when I submit the form via mouse-click.. I see the data via $_POST. If the users presses ENTER, the data is never captured and I never see that data from the hidden fields.

Any idea what's wrong here? Note, I've tried almost all the event handlers onblur, onclick, onchange..etc.

```
<form  method="post" name="something" action="xxSome.php">
  <div class="s_row">
    <label for="zippy">Enter Zip Code</label>
    <input id="zipcode_home"  tabindex="2" type="text" onkeypress="javascript:getCityByZipHome(document.getElementById('zipcode_home').value, this.form.elements['city3']);javascript:getStateByZipHome(document.getElementById('zipcode_home').value, this.form.elements['state3']);" name="zipcode_home"/>
    <input id="state3" name="state3"type="hidden"/>
    <input id="city3" name="city3" type="hidden"/>
    <input type="submit"  value="Start Now!"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

I've tried adding onsubmit @ the form level as such:

```
<form  method="post" name="something" action="xxSome.php" onsubmit="javascript:getCityByZipHome(document.getElementById('zipcode_home').value, this.form.elements['city3']);javascript:getStateByZipHome(document.getElementById('zipcode_home').value, this.form.elements['state3']);">
  <div class="s_row">
    <label for="zippy">Enter Zip Code</label>
    <input id="zipcode_home"  tabindex="2" type="text"  name="zipcode_home"/>
    <input id="state3" name="state3"type="hidden"/>
    <input id="city3" name="city3" type="hidden"/>
    <input type="submit"  value="Start Now!"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I've tried onblur without any luck @ the input level as such:

```
<form  method="post" name="something" action="xxSome.php">
  <div class="s_row">
    <label for="zippy">Enter Zip Code</label>
    <input id="zipcode_home"  tabindex="2" type="text" onblur="javascript:getCityByZipHome(document.getElementById('zipcode_home').value, this.form.elements['city3']);javascript:getStateByZipHome(document.getElementById('zipcode_home').value, this.form.elements['state3']);" name="zipcode_home"/>
    <input id="state3" name="state3"type="hidden"/>
    <input id="city3" name="city3" type="hidden"/>
    <input type="submit"  value="Start Now!"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

**After all the messing around, I actually never solved the issue; rather, I disabled the ENTER key as a submit method.**

I have some pretty serious time constraints, but I'm sure this will come up later and I will definitely come back to this issue.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `onkeypress`? Do you see the posted data? If so, there might be some preventDefault happening somewhere, or something like that.

Comment: I changed onkeypress to onchange and same issue

Comment: do you have firebug?  If not get it and put a breakpoint in your methods, do your steps that are failing and see if they are getting called before the page submits when you hit enter.  I tried with my sample and it worked.  if you send your code i can test it with firebug if you dont know how to use it.

Comment: don't have it and don't know how to use it.. never too late to learn. I'll get it and see if I can debugg (I at least can use a debugger like Eclipses')

Comment: For html and javascript firebug is awesome, its a firefox plugin. If it works when you click the button it should work when you hit enter, you will definitely find out what is going one once you get firebug.  just go to the script tab, enable them, reload the page, and then put a breakpoint just like you would with eclipse, when you hit enter if it doesnt stop then its not calling hte code, if it does stop then you can inspect the objects and see what is going on.  Good luck, let us know how it turns out

Comment: is there a way to supress ENTER on that form? That way users have to click submit?

Comment: Change the type of the submit to button and then add on onClick method to it.  ie instead of <input type="submit" value="submit"/>  make it <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="document.forms["formId"].submit();" />  but you need an id on the form to do that.  I would be interested though in finding the cause of what is going wrong.  Did you try firebug?

Comment: You should probably use `getElementById('city3')` rather than `this.form.elements['city3'])`

Comment: I updated my thread.. I tried using Firebug, but time constraints forced me to look for an alternate solution.. I disable the ENTER key as a way of submission.. I will come back to this when I have more time....

Answer (score 0):

You should do the getcitybyzip and getstatebyzip in the form onSubmit.

Comment: I suspect that is supposed to be autocomplete, so it can't be in `onSubmit`.

Comment: @Amadan those fields are hidden, so it does not matter if it is auto completed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the submit to button and then add on onClick method to it. ie instead of  make it  but you need an id on the form to do that. I would be interested though in finding the cause of what is going wrong. Did you try firebug?

Comment: Somewhat of a late followup, but like I mentioned before, I ended up throwing a onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13" @ the <form> tag